# Tag Review: What do to if I only like a certain part of the edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I got this item in the suggested edit queue (my first tag review):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19838462

While I like the addition of the API Browser I do not like LinQPad classified as Build Tools. That's wrong in my book.

What to do: Accept and remove the bad part afterward - or reject and add only the good part?

Comment: I now wondered who decided it was a good idea to put .NET Core release date under that tag... I will remove that as soon as your edit is approved/rejected

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No idea. Go ahead. It was approved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having incorrect information in a tag description or excerpt is a more severe problem than having incomplete information (or none at all).  On that basis, I'd be inclined to reject the edit.

Answer (score 12):

Suggested edits having incorrect information is destructive, and is better to be rejected. Also, the "good" part may also be seen as questionable.

Just simply reject the edit, or even perform "reject and edit". Do not accept or even improve suggested edits having clearly incorrect or irrelevant information.

Comment: For reviews of tag wiki and tag excerpt edits, the options to "Reject and Edit" and "Improve Edit" are not available until the user has full tag wiki/excerpt editing privileges at 20k reputation. Given that the user asking about this has ~5k reputation, these options are not available.